# Vuejs using v-model binding with listening from child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

You suppose we have this `html` tag in parent component which i want to observe that from child using `v-model`:

```html
<textarea v-model="email"></textarea>
```

like with that:

```html
<template>
    <textarea v-model="caption"></textarea>
    <print :caption="caption"/>
</template>

<script>
import print from "./print";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            caption: ''
        }
    },
    components: {
        print
    }
}
</script>
```

`print` child component:

```html
<template>
    <p v-html="caption"></p>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props:{
      caption : String
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$emit('caption', this.$el.innerText)
    }
}
</script>
```

now after each typing in parent component how can i observe from child parent and show in `p` tag? this code is not correct and i can't resolve problem?

Comment: it should work, I tried it out

Comment: It looks (and works - tested) just fine as is